# Change input range color like on youtube

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using Youtube API and I'm trying to use a costum input range for yotube player. I want to do something like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtzv3.png). I want to do that using this with yellow color.

```
<div class="range-video col-xs-6">
  <input type="range" id="progress-bar" value="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: Uppas1975 is this what you wanted? Accept answer if it is

Comment: @urbz yeah..but not working using youtube API.

Answer (score -1):

When specifying the color of the progress bar using API, according to the [document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#color):

> This parameter specifies the color that will be used in the player's video progress bar to highlight the amount of the video that the viewer has already seen. **Valid parameter values are red and white**, and, by default, the player uses the color red in the video progress bar. See the [YouTube API blog](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2011/08/coming-soon-dark-player-for-embeds_5.html) for more information about color options.

```
<iframe width="560" height="349"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9h1swNWgP8Q?theme=light&color=red"
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The valid color for the progress bar as of now is only white and red.

I hope this helps.